# Specify fields to be returned with find_each?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, find, mongomapper

We currently have this batched code using MongoMapper which is still taking longer than we would like:

```
User.find_each(conditions: {is_active: true}, batch_size: 500) do |user|
  # simple stuff that only requires a couple fields from user
end
```

Is there some way to tell it to only return the fields we need from the User model like you can do with a non-batched find?

```
User.where(is_active:true).fields(:field1, :field2).all
```

Changing the batch size hasn't helped so we're looking for other ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoMapper's [`fields`](http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/querying.html#fields) filter should work fine with `find_each`. But, when used at the end of a query chain, find_each returns an enumerator rather than calling the block, so you have to add an extra `.each`:

```
User.where(is_active:true).fields(:field1, :field2).find_each.each { |user| ...}
```

- Source: [plucky/lib/plucky/query.rb:54](https://github.com/jnunemaker/plucky/blob/master/lib/plucky/query.rb#L54)
- Versus: [mongomapper/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying:13](https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/blob/master/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb#L13)

Comment: Edited answer: need an extra `.each` on the end.  Seems wrong, so I filed a bug: https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/issues/386

Answer (score 3):

try

```
User.where(is_active:true).select("field1, field2").find_each { |user| p user }
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I"m using MongoMapper so that syntax doesn't work...